# recursively git pull for all of the git submodules simply

Tags: git, git-submodules

My personal repository has some repositories as submodules. And the following command

```
$ git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

was faced with the following result right after entering ruby repository because ruby repository seems that it does not have a master branch and "git pull" stopped.

```
Entering 'rails'
From git://github.com/rails/rails
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Entering 'roo'
From git://github.com/hmcgowan/roo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Entering 'ruby'
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
Stopping at 'ruby'; script returned non-zero status.
```

So my question is **`what should I do to git pull for all of submodules only by git command?`** Should I do make a script to this? I hope just ONE command line provided from git will make this.

Comment: If you don't want `git submodule foreach ...`to stop when an error occurs in one of the sub-repos just add `||:` to the command, i.e. `git submodule foreach 'git pull origin master || :'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git` submodules are typically in detached-HEAD states, and thus `git pull` on them can't figure out what you mean when it comes to the merge phase. If all you are trying to do is get the latest changes into the repository, try `git submodule foreach git fetch` instead. If you want to get each submodules `master` updated to its respective `origin/master`, then you can follow up with `git submodule foreach git checkout master; git submodule foreach git merge origin/master`.

Then, of course, you need to decide what version of each submodule you want your main repository to use (I would not recommend blindly going with `origin/master` all the time - it may be unstable - better to pick a known-good tag or something), check out those versions in the submodules, and follow up with the appropriate `git add`s and `git commit` in your main repository.

Answer (score 7):

Just add `|| true` to your submodule command:

```
git submodule foreach 'git commit -m "my commit message" || true'
```

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) might avoid that error, by improving `git submodule update`, which influences `git submodule pull`.

"`git submodule update`" attempts two different kinds of "`git fetch`"
against the upstream repository to grab a commit bound at the submodule's path, but it incorrectly gave up if the first kind (i.e. a normal fetch) failed, making the second "last resort" one (i.e. fetching an exact commit object by object name) ineffective.
This has been corrected.

See [commit e30d833](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e30d833671d634ea6455fd49596ac7339a4915b1) (15 May 2018) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a173ddd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a173dddf4483ed11b228077078becc8b65174b46), 30 May 2018)</sup>

> ### `git-submodule.sh`: try harder to fetch a submodule

> This is the logical continuum of [fb43e31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb43e31f2b43076e7a30c9cd00d0241cb8cf97eb) (submodule: try harder to
> fetch needed sha1 by direct fetching sha1, 2016-02-23, Git 2.8.0) and fixes it as some assumptions were not correct.
>
> The commit states:
>
> > If `$sha1` was not part of the default fetch ... fail ourselves here assumes that the `fetch_in_submodule` only fails when the serverside does not support fetching by sha1.
>
> There are other failures, why such a fetch may fail, such as
>
> ```
> fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD
> ```
>
> which can happen if the remote side doesn't advertise HEAD and we do not
> have a local fetch refspec.
>
> Not advertising HEAD is allowed by the protocol spec and would happen,
> if HEAD points at an unborn branch for example.
>
> Not having a local fetch refspec can happen when submodules are fetched
> shallowly, as then git-clone doesn't setup a fetch refspec.
>
> **So do try even harder for a submodule by ignoring the exit code of the
> first fetch and rather relying on the following `is_tip_reachable` to
> see if we try fetching again**.

---

Note: the error message on submodule fetch has been improved with Git 2.22 (Q2 2019)

See [commit bd5e567](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd5e567dc75abae58cb364d1e55cbaf67edb8c98) (13 Mar 2019) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 32414ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32414ceb854de44a9b4b74c975ae410713a17c99), 09 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### submodule: explain first attempt failure clearly

> When cloning with `--recurse-submodules` a superproject with at least one
> submodule with HEAD pointing to an unborn branch, the clone goes
> something like this:
>
> ```
> Cloning into 'test'...
> <messages about cloning of superproject>
> Submodule '<name>' (<uri>) registered for path '<submodule path>'
> Cloning into '<submodule path>'...
> fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD
> Unable to fetch in submodule path '<submodule path>'
> <messages about fetching with SHA-1>
> From <uri>
>     * branch            <hash> -> FETCH_HEAD
> Submodule path '<submodule path>': checked out '<hash>'
> ```
>
> In other words, first, a fetch is done with no hash arguments (that is,
> a fetch of HEAD) resulting in a "`Couldn't find remote ref HEAD`" error;
> then, a fetch is done given a hash, which succeeds.
>
> This commit improves the notice to be clearer that we are retrying the
> fetch, and that the previous messages (in particular, the fatal errors
> from fetch) do not necessarily indicate that the whole command fails.

---

Note that, with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), reimplementation of parts of "[`git submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e78db9d3037eba812591857e7b44e69b97b329f4/Documentation/git-submodule.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule))</sup> in C continues.

See [commit c51f8f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c51f8f94e5b3d6a8d190d9901ea0c5b83e30c3aa) (24 Aug 2021) by [Atharva Raykar (`tfidfwastaken`)](https://github.com/tfidfwastaken).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e78db9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e78db9d3037eba812591857e7b44e69b97b329f4), 20 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`submodule--helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c51f8f94e5b3d6a8d190d9901ea0c5b83e30c3aa): run update procedures from C
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Shourya Shukla</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Atharva Raykar</sup>

> Add a new submodule--helper subcommand `run-update-procedure` that runs the update procedure if the SHA1 of the submodule does not match what the superproject expects.

That means the `is_tip_reachable` shell method mentioned above does no longer exist.

---

The same rewrite in C goes on with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), and "[`git submodule update`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7649bfbaa2be9472e2c9ee2fab7525887d4c0fc9/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L136)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N%7C--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f%7C--force--checkout%7C--rebase%7C--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--filterltfilterspecgt--ltpathgt82308203))</sup>.

See [commit c9d2562](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9d256249375c7b8a1773139791448860b5789ff), [commit 104744f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/104744f91d9d04763ab2df06308bfa3c0b464f84), [commit 97cb977](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97cb977c8243c3393a85d662456a1e161596f211), [commit 29a5e9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29a5e9e1ffeadb0555fdd2f366f1cb7259462ab9), [commit 1012a5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1012a5cbc3fe4bcfae278a8103e60054d2674784), [commit e441966](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e44196659634fdc42672888f5a91e94303052284), [commit 1a0b78c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a0b78c9537571c18bafc4ac6e3fc16fe6b63c84), [commit f7bdb32](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7bdb3291873f0c10ad63015b18d1caf1ec719d7) (04 Mar 2022) by [Glen Choo (`chooglen`)](https://github.com/chooglen).
See [commit 3ce52cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ce52cba5b283af1f5dbebfe43aeea5d3421dac6), [commit 5312a85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5312a850b882d5e4b61b3590a151d41d9a1e8767), [commit a77c3fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a77c3fcb5ec535507e1e71da4f642151f65b4b17) (04 Mar 2022) by [Atharva Raykar (`tfidfwastaken`)](https://github.com/tfidfwastaken).
See [commit ed9c848](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed9c84853e99e2dbbb2b49898ca7badfe1686474), [commit aca8568](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aca8568e2c342b1764837df29468ed498b5e6dcd) (04 Mar 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7649bfb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7649bfbaa2be9472e2c9ee2fab7525887d4c0fc9), 23 Mar 2022)</sup>

And the rewrite foes on with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), which includes preparation to remove `git-submodule.sh` and replace it with a builtin.

See [commit 69d9446](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69d94464e14de859ff56bcde7ebe0132201eceb9), [commit 1b6e200](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b6e2001c7fd96214b1fe2f910fad5cbb60b607a), [commit 64f48ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64f48ad1f036be2a09273051b28bfacf471cbfcc), [commit 82ff877](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82ff87789bdd972c9746ec184ae9464e58c8d29b), [commit 46e87b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46e87b548290ca59644a9d1265fe7451a6e64d8e), [commit d50d848](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d50d8485ef03898a4f51fd99daa65217f2b713ae), [commit 435285b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/435285bd82a9356b8e13f83cee77a2db4a0e7f0e), [commit 44874cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44874cbd19afb6ee6fa7dad01dbe6eec161cc94b), [commit cc74a4a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc74a4ac7255510b4a928d4973dcfcc746d74e8f) (08 Nov 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1107a39](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1107a3963b566e41d25ee1a7e152db9b08a8fc6e), 23 Nov 2022)</sup>