# Managing Multiple Repositories (Forks) in My One Project

Tags: git, github

I have 4 forks in one project:

https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction-platform

https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction

https://github.com/reactioncommerce/example-storefront

https://github.com/reaction-contrib/meteor-payments-braintree

I want to pull from **Owner** repo his changes, and push to **My** repo his and my changes **but** problem is in clarity. I must do 4x "git pull" from 4 repositories and 4x "git push" to my 4 forks. Its not handy I think
If I had 50 forks it can take long time to push them all to my forks.
I want one project where I can push all by git push.

Is there some good solution? And if solution begin with "create new project on github..." my next question is for what is fork if I should create a new project with cloned repository?

I hope you understand and Thank you for any help with git:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create one parent repository with those n repos [as **submodules**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

- you can clone/pull all of them in one command ([starting with Git 2.18](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671717/6309), and [mainly with Git 2.23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3797061/6309)):

  ```
  git clone --recurse-submodules --remote-submodules
  # or, once cloned
  it submodule update --remote
  ```
- push your changes in one go (since [Git 1.7 and 2.12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10878273/6309)):

  ```
  git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
  ```